# How to port python2 code to python3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I find out the following code that print shellcode or machine code of the objdump in the output but in python3 i can't run it. How can I port it to python3:

```
import subprocess
import sys
from subprocess import Popen


num_of_args = len(sys.argv)
binary_file = sys.argv[1]

#| awk -F'[:]' '{print $2}' | awk -F'[ ]' '{print $1}' | tr -d '[[:space:]]'

proc = subprocess.Popen(['arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump','-d',binary_file], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
  line = proc.stdout.readline()
  if line != '':
    array = line.rstrip().split(':')
    if len(array) > 1:
        if array[1]:
                array2 =  array[1].split(' ')
                array2 = array2[0].lstrip().rstrip()
                if array2:
                        sc_part = '"'
                        sc_part += '\\x'
                        sc_part += '\\x'.join(a+b for a,b in zip(array2[::2], array2[1::2]))
                        sc_part += '"'
                        print sc_part
  else:
    break
```

Comment: Please provide the specifics about what exactly is failing in the code you are trying to port to Python 3. Maybe someone might come along and port all this code for you, and you move on. But in general dumping code and asking the community to just "fix the things" is bad form. There are tons of information out there about differences between python 2 and python 3. When you run the code and get a syntax error, try to isolate the area and then look up why this is happening. You will learn much more this way.

Comment: when i run the code with python3 it shows the error :     array = line.rstrip().split(':')
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#using-2to3) tool that comes bundled with the python distribution. An example of its usage is this:

`foo.py`

```
def foo:
    for i in xrange(5):
        print i,

foo()
```

In the command line, you'll type:

```
$ 2to3 -w foo.py
```

`foo.py` (post command):

```
def foo():
    for i in range(5):
        print(i, end=' ')

foo()
```

---

Running `2to3` on your code, it appears only the print needs changing: `print(sc_part)`

Comment: I change it but when i run code with py3 it shows the error:     array = line.rstrip().split(':')
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API

Comment: @YuriProshkin Yeah, it is read as bytes. You need to convert it: `line.decode().rstrip().split(':')` You would have got the same error on python2.

Comment: Thank you. It works now. But the loop of the code never exit. Where is the problem of the loop control?

Comment: @YuriProshkin Data is read in as bytes. You are comparing a normal string `''` to the byte string `b''` which is returned when there is no more output. Change to `if line != b'':`

Answer (score 0):

`print(sc_part)` may well be the only thing you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you pasted the stacktrace.

Anyways, try replacing `print sc_part` with `print(sc_part)`

Furthermore, you can read all of the changes in Python3 [here](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html).